# I want to show page as Category Page where as all pages are loading as Content pages

Tags: spartacus-storefront

[Page response is coming as content page. Load the page as Category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFAjJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Spartacus requests a specific page type depending on what it thinks the URL relates to & the server responds on that basis.  Therefore you need to look at the request from Spartacus, rather than the response.  Content Page is the default type, and it will only request Category Pages for the configured category URLs. See: [Adding and Customizing Routes](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/) in the Spartacus documentation